# Is it allowed to talk about the use of external sites such as myanimelist

Tags: discussion

Title state's most of my question.

I have been wondering as it is the anime/manga section can we talk about site's such as 
[myanimlist](http://myanimlist.net)

Why should we use it. why is it easy to use and such

Or talk about certain site's were we can watch/read certain anime/ manga ?

Some serie's can't be watched on one site but can be seen on another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very few of such sites (Online sites for watching anime/reading manga) are legal. There's a giant legal blur over these sites because the law changes from country to country and from site to site based on usage.

For that reason we decided to avoid the trap hole and disallow these questions completely.

Unless the site in question is official, and the question is constructive (i.e.not "Should I use this site?"), it's probably not welcome here. If your question answers the above criteria, go ahead and ask it! We'll be happy to answer it.

As for *My Anime List* specifically, it's very likely that any question you may ask here is either off-topic (as it should be directed to their support), or not constructive (as it would be a recommendation question).

So here's what you do, ask it anyway. At the worst case, it would be closed.

Comment: that pretty much answers it  unless it is constructive towards the answer/question do not use practicaly :)

Comment: Huh? How is MAL illegal? Just because a lot of its users illegally acquire their anime does not make the site itself illegal.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's true that sites like MAL are illegal, at least in the US (where Stack Exchange is based). It hosts a few images per series, but that could potentially be fair use, and there aren't any downloads available, though they do link to fansub groups (which is questionable, but 2nd order links are probably fine).  However, streaming sites and manga databases are very clearly illegal in most cases (excluding Crunchyroll and a few other simulcast sites). In any case I agree that these discussions are still not constructive whether or not they are legal.

Comment: Not MAL specifically, I was referring more to sites for watching anime and manga. I'm sorry if that was unclear. About MAL, it's very likely that any question you may ask here is either off-topic (as it should be directed to their support), or not constructive (as it would be a recommendation question). Here's what you do @Dimitrimx, ask it anyway. At the worst case, it would be closed.

Comment: Okay i do understand it now then ^^

Comment: Also @all, note that my opinion isn't necesarily the community's opinion. If anyone has a different opinion than mine, don't hesitate to downvote, comment, and give your own answer. The community's collective opinion matters much more than one of a single moderator.

Answer (score 2):

While MAL may link to fansub groups, they also have a credible and moderated (moderated as in normal users cannot post to the news section without their submission being reviewed by staff) [news section](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?board=15). From my own experience on MAL, I know that at least one of their news staff is fluent in Japanese and occasionally posts translated news before ANN.

In [one of my own answers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/917/107), I included a link to a MAL news article as a source. I found the MAL article much more useful than the equivalent ANN article because the ANN article simply summarized the tweets as "careless remarks" while the MAL article translated the whole tweets (which are probably deleted by now).

While asking questions about how to use MAL are certainly off topic for this SE, I don't think links to MAL news articles as sources should be discredited just because they link to fansub groups on other parts of the site.

If ANN also included links to fansub groups, would we disallow them too? How would we be able to find sources for some answers?

Answer (score 1):

MAL links to fansub groups and is therefore sketchy in terms of legality. The same applies to any other site that provides information on fansubbers and scanlators.

Most mainstream titles and their associated characters, cast, and other staff are listed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal%3aAnime_and_manga). [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/)'s encyclopaedia is also a safe bet. Even [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com) lists many anime titles. [Wikia](http://www.wikia.com/Wikia) is another option for popular titles.